# How to run OWIN code beside a ASP.NET WebForms app?

Tags: asp.net, owin

I have a legacy ASP.NET WebForms application and I wrote some new code using OWIN. How can I make them coexist inside a single application?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The whole point of owin was to get rid of the System.Web dependency.

Comment: The new code is not dependent on System.Web -- I can leverage this in unit testing and so on, but I am not yet prepared to throw away all the functional stuff that serves well. It's nice that I am not forced to make the transition at once.

Comment: Just dive in! :) The steeper the learning curve, the more you are learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This eluded me for an hour or so, but then I finally found this trivial code sample: [ASP.NET Routes Sample](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Katana/AspNetRoutes/Global.asax.cs). There is this method [MapOwinPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollectionextensions.mapowinpath(v=vs.111).aspx) that takes a URL root and startup delegate and... that's it.